# Different look of QSpinBox on MacOs

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I developed a simple QT application on Windows using QT creator 5.8 with good result. I used a simple form with QSpinBox.
To fix the color of the QSpinBox I wrote in the related style sheet

```
color:rgb(255,255,255);
```

Then I moved the application on MaxOs but the look of QSpinBox changed.

[image: QSpinBox shown on mac]

Did you have a similar problem ? How did you fix it ?
Thank you very much for your help and cooperation

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the QWidget appearance actually depends on the platform. One (limited) solution is to use the palette, with [setForegroundRole](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setForegroundRole)

The other is to use stylesheets, like you did, but you very likely will have to redefine more to obtain the desired result, and result will of course depend on the platform. You can actually make the result completely custom using only stylesheet. Just make sure to set the "border" style to avoid problems.

Here is Qt documentation about style sheets: [Qt StyleSheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html)